# Making Command in bash script to run php script

Tags: php, bash, email, phpmailer, sender

I've been making an email sender that's based on **phpmailer**. Everything is good, email sent, but i want to make my sender simpler.

When I run my script, the usual command is `php MKSENDER`, and I want to make it just like running from a bash script like `./MKSENDER --SEND`, any suggest how to build it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line.

Placing `#!/usr/bin/env php` at the top of your file should work as long as you have execute permissions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo "Hello World";
```

You can then utilize the native function [getopt()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php) to get options, or parse [argv](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) yourself.

Comment: Hello devon, the original php is there, can i change it to [php mysender.php] ?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env php
php MKSENDER
when im using that its just print out php MKSENDER,

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env
php MKSENDER when im putting this script, its doesnt show anything, i have chmod the script

Comment: You save the script in a file called `MKSENDER`, and the first line *inside* the file is `#!/usr/bin/env php` - and don't put anything else after it on that first line. Put the rest of your script after that. The first line just lets the shell know what interpreter (language) to use to run the script.

Comment: oh i just have to add the #!/usr/bin/env php in my MKSENDER? and run it ./MKSENDER